# Installing PCIe SSD on an enclosure for NVME Thunderbolt 3

Tags: mac, ssd, external-hard-drive, pci-express, enclosures

I have OWC Aura X2 PCIe 1TB SSD, and I’m trying to purchase a right enclosure.

I see most enclosures are for either NVME and SATA. I read some articles that PCIe and NVME share the same lanes, but they are technically different..?

My question is that whether I can use a Thunserbolt 3 NVME SSD enclosure for my OWC PCIe SSD.

Or should I get a specific enclosure just for PCIe?

Comment: “I read some articles that PCIe and NVME share the same lanes, but they are technically different..?“ - Yes; They are indeed different. They share the same lanes to the processor on the motherboard. If your talking about an enclosure they wouldn’t share the same lanes. A M.2 slot that supports NVMe most likely would NOT also support SATA. Focus on an enclosure that supports NVMe drives.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a Thunderbolt 3 NVME SSD enclosure for your OWC PCIe SSD.